# How to remove duplicates from an array of JSON objects in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to remove duplicate entries based on the id for the following json, but it seems I am not able to parse the JSON correctly, My array of JSON is as follows:

```
[ '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"57"},{"name":"sample","id":"acc"}]}\n',
  '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"},{"name":"sample","id":"ac"}]}\n',
  '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"},{"name":"sample","id":"ac"}]}\n',
  '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"}]}\n',
]
```

the output should be

```
{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"57"},{"name":"sample","id":"acc"}]}
```

My Code is as follows:

```
removeDups: async function(listent){
      for (i = 0; i < listent.length; i++){
        console.log(listent.length)
         for (j = 0; j < listent.length; j++){
           console.log(listent[j])
       }
        var standardsList = this.arrUnique(listent);
        console.log("standard", standardsList)
    }
    },

    arrUnique: function (arr) {
      var cleaned = [];
      arr.forEach(function(itm) {
          var unique = true;
          cleaned.forEach(function(itm2) {
              if (_.isEqual(itm, itm2)) unique = false;
          });
          if (unique)  cleaned.push(itm);
      });
      return cleaned;

      }
```

Comment: Thanks. For the second and third items, `acc` and `57` are the unique `id`s, but because the first items `id`s are all the same, the `id` used will be the `id` shared by all of them, is that the rule? Find the unique `id`, or use whatever ID is shared by all?

Comment: @NidhiSharma you could use _.uniq to solve it. But, you will need to parse the response into form that can be ingested into JS (using JSON.parse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/c0pkw5ju/

The core functions are:

```
var val = array.reduce(function (acc, val) {
    return acc.concat(val.entries)
}, [])

console.log(_.unique(val, function (v) {
    return v.id
}))
```

Basically, you need to convert your `\n` separated JSON response to a JS object which can be consumed as indicated. Let me know if this not help.

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "sample",
    "id": "8d"
  },
  {
    "name": "sample",
    "id": "57"
  },
  {
    "name": "sample",
    "id": "acc"
  },
  {
    "name": "sample",
    "id": "50"
  },
  {
    "name": "sample",
    "id": "ac"
  }
]
```

UPDATE: 
Assuming response to be:

```
var response = ['{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"57"},{"name":"sample","id":"acc"}]}\n',
    '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"},{"name":"sample","id":"ac"}]}\n',
    '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"},{"name":"sample","id":"ac"}]}\n',
    '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"}]}\n',
]
```

If you processed response as indicated here:

```
var array = response.map(function(val) {
    return JSON.parse(val.trim())
})
```

then core functions should work.

Comment: I tried this and it worked absolutely fine, the only issue is i am not able to convert the /n from the JSON to convert it into JS Object. I tried JSON.parse but it prints the same output as the arr.

Comment: @NidhiSharma hold on ... let me see if I can write something up for that as well...

Answer (score 1):

Run the code snippet and you'll see the exact same output as you mentioned in your question. I hope this will be helpful to you (and to others). Happy coding **:)**

```js
const data = ['{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"57"},{"name":"sample","id":"acc"}]}\n',
    '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"},{"name":"sample","id":"ac"}]}\n',
    '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"},{"name":"sample","id":"ac"}]}\n',
    '{"entries":[{"name":"sample","id":"8d"},{"name":"sample","id":"50"}]}\n',
];

// Let us first format it correctly 
const formatted = data.map(x => {
    return JSON.parse(x.trim())
});

// Let's loop over our newly created array and push unique values into a new one

let uniqueNames = [];
let uniqueObj = [];

for(let i = 0; i < formatted.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(data[i]._id) === -1){
       uniqueObj.push(data[i])
       uniqueNames.push(data[i]._id);
       }        
    }

// Let's take that one step further and display it exactly as you wanted it to be :)
const iterator = uniqueObj.values();

for (const value of iterator) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: @NidhiSharma The pleasure is all mine. Please consider an upvote and accept my answer (when you get the chance to) **:)**

Comment: sure I have upvoted it already, Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796929/how-to-use-for-loop-along-with-the-request-get-to-get-the-first-few-parts-from-u, do you have any thoughts on this